# Is there any way to relate the induced EMF from an alternator to the DC current that is used in the field winding?

Tags: electrical-engineering, electromagnetism, generator

I'm trying to simulate the open circuit saturation of an alternator. Basically, by changing the amount of current that is going through the field windings (rotor), the voltage induced in the armature windings (stator)  can be changed. By using the law of electromagnetic induction, it can be observed that the induced voltage is directly proportional to the flux created by the field winding. Does anyone have ny ideas on how to relate the flux to the DC current?

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, the induced voltage and the magnetic flux are related.
According to Faraday's law, this gives :
[image: 1]
Using the definition of an inductor, we can obtain:
[image]
Note that in your case, the change in magnetic flux seen by the stator occurs because of rotation, so both the rotational speed and the flux magnitude have an impact on the induced EMF.
From the stator point of view we have:
[image]
Finally, for one coil composed of N turns:
[image]
And this should be a good starting point to think about your problem.